# How to fetch the mobile number in android 4.0?

Tags: android, phone-number

Hi i am using the code mentioned below to fetch my own number from an android phone.

```
    TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) this
     .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
   String phoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

This code works perfect until 2.3 version of android, and the problem is i need it to be working on android version 4.0 and above is there any code available for this.

thank you

Comment: Are you sure your SIM card has a number on it?

Comment: 1.the same code works in my own 2.3 device , but it is not working in my 4.0 device it has sim card

Comment: That's strange because the public API is still there...

Comment: are you sure will this code work for all versions

Comment: @Gopic.s That's fine, and it should work in 4.0 too. But not all sim cards have the phone number on them. Try putting the SIM card from the 2.3 device in the 4.0 one and running the code.

Comment: oooh thats great i ill check it and say soon, thanks for the head up man